# SSRS Lifecycle Charts

Tags: reporting-services

[Lifecycle report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/150fW.jpg)

Before I spend a few hundred hours working on a report I wanted to get some feedback to determine if SSRS can do what I want to accomplish.

I have a database that stores data about product lifecycles. The database stores a variety of stages that a product may be in the form "Product Name: Stage Description: start date: end date".

When I query the database the data comes back with one row per stage, so if a product has 4 stages (example: planned, Production, Retire, Remove) I get 4 rows of data. This is the first problem that can probably be solved in SQL by concatenating all stages into a single row.

The data needs to be displayed horizontally plotted against a time scale (in years and quarters) with different colors to represent each stage using the associated start and end date for each stage. In addition, there are special conditions where we may pay extended support for a product that has gone "end of life" from a manufacturer. I would like to indicate where this occurs with a symbol (like a $ sign).

If SSRS cannot do this I would be interested in other suggested products.

Comments, opinions and suggestions appreciated.

[Lifecycle Report]

Comment: Was your plan to attach an example of the report to this question? Where is says [Lifecycle Report]? Right now, everything about this sounds doable, entirely in SSRS. It will be a complex report, but achievable with the tool just the same. Research the SSRS Matrix, and conditional formatting.

Comment: I agree with R. Richards, it might be a bit awkward but this sounds perfectly feasible with SSRS.